# Referencing crosstab grand total field in another formula

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, crystal-reports-xi, crosstab

I need to refer the grandtotal field generated in the cross tab - in a formula field.
Is there a way to do it? The database fields can be referenced using table.fieldname but how to identify the grandtotal column?

I then need to show a curve based on the totals vs something else, but identifying the totals in a formula is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be easiest to calculate the total again. In the report footer, add a summary field on table.fieldname, and set the summary to **Sum**.

Or create a formula: `Sum({table.fieldname})`